# Random factorized numbers

Tags: math, number-theory, fastest-code, probability-theory, factoring

## Input

The code should take an integer \$n\$ between 1 and 1000.

## Output

The code should output positive integers with \$n\$ bits. Accompanying each integer should be its full factorization. Each integer should be a uniformly random \$n\$ bit number.

## Score

The score for your code will be the number of integers it outputs, with their factorizations, in ten seconds on my Ubuntu PC when \$n = 500\$.

## Primality testing

If you need to test if a number is prime, you can use any method that is any of:

- Provably always correct
- Not proven to always be correct but for which there is no known example where it is incorrect
- Provably has probability at most \$2^{-30}\$ of giving the wrong answer.

As always,this challenge is *per* language and I will keep a scoreboard for the answers given.

## Is this possible?

The two best known methods are [Bach's algorithm](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ecs812-1/pfrn.pdf) and a simpler one by [Kalai](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/akalai/genfactor/web/factor/factor.html).

## Leaderboard

- **4** in **Rust** by mousetail
- **500** in **Python 3.10** by Command Master
- **14406** in **C++** by Command Master

Comment: This is probably impossible; you've got about a 1 in 100,000 chance of your 1000-bit number being the product of two 500 bit primes, which you won't be able to factorise before the heat death of the universe.

Comment: @Neil It turns out there are methods to do this. You don't do any factorization but rather construct the number with its factors

Comment: How do you construct them to be uniformly random?

Comment: @Neil See update.

Comment: Am I allowed to do some preprocessing for all numbers together, or do I have to do it separately for each number?

Comment: @CommandMaster Could you explain what you have in mind? Obviously you can't just precompute the answer for each n.

Comment: I want to do some precomputation (for example factor all numbers up to \$10^6\$), and then reuse it for all numbers

Comment: @CommandMaster That seems reasonable.

Comment: Can I assume the Riemann Hypothesis?

Comment: Yes! That seems a fair assumption

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org)

Thanks to @AndersKaseorg for many improvements and bug fixes.

```python
import math
import random
import time

import sympy


def gen_factor(N):
    while True:
        j = random.randint(1, N.bit_length() - 1)
        q = (1 << j) + random.randrange(1 << j)
        if q > N:
            continue
        Nt = N // q
        if random.random() >= math.log(q, N) * (((Nt + 1) >> 1) << j) / N:
            continue
        p, a = sympy.perfect_power(q) or (q, 1)
        if random.random() >= 1 / a:
            continue
        if sympy.isprime(p):
            return p, a, Nt


def bach(N):
    if N <= 10 ** 5:
        x = random.randint(N//2 + 1, N)
        return x, sympy.factorint(x)
    while True:
        p, a, Nt = gen_factor(N)
        newx, factx = bach(Nt)
        newx *= p ** a
        if random.random() < math.log(N / 2, newx):
            factx[p] = factx.get(p, 0) + a
            return newx, factx


def gen(n):
    return bach((1 << n) - 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.perf_counter()
    a = []
    while time.perf_counter() - t < 10:
        a.append(gen(500))

    print('Generated', len(a), 'numbers in 10 seconds:')
    print(*a, sep='\n')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVRNj5swEL30xK-YGzbLElhppWoVcu2NS3vbriwHhoRVMI4xSvJbetlL-6P6azrmIyHbbWOJD8O8ec8zz_7xS5_stlFvbz87W95__v3pa1Xrxliopd1647uRqmjqaWarGr1p0p5qffI8r8ASNqhEKXPbGJbxJw9oHLbVDuGb6XCYu_EK6Zgxco9KWZaEkEXryoodqo3dMg73kPAzYk8IlsByCa8c7uZgujY4_TrHVyVBVpBdON3IG2Ur1eH5Y2YpbwaLBezn0Fn6piYpq7QvRrRrNmxPQjkEwBgj9B2JhNXK3Qdti5ucOgRJrH3ZIo2mxNwK3RzQsD2HxoCjSPgNPQkxyRtMhBxYqlYbahnT_Bph0HZG9YpoVXZs4lrm23P7KEcGS-KLIQjg8YI__t3DbLF4cBVxFfLecRzDUctgDxd-5P80yKSIOK4sdQ5QeKCM7rvTMSi2178hSEE70fJ_pVxeOks-gIewx76rU8_zrF-Iqn-NNmgZaYydF-VHJZ3pu2wNpsa8Y1Ave7CuGv1Ou6oEIZSsUQhIU_CFqGWlhPAHqCuJ2369c0TedMqScYaVO1s9v8yK-kEg0VhadBJfVigjqTWqgjmJj3HMSUbfhL5L_hdUaKTFwg-BNieTPARfdfUaTQuVcs5okbxXtE8-nwED6mCLOvW_K58PZ8t4xExHzR8)

This is a simple implementation of [Bach's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bach%27s_algorithm), just to get the challenge going. Make sure you have `gmpy2` installed when running. Can generate around \$130\$ numbers on my computer.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer!

Comment: @Simd could you give the amount of numbers it generates in 10 seconds on your computer?

Comment: It was quite a lot faster without pypy (but with gmpy2). I think sympy isprime is slow in pypy but fast with gmpy2.

Comment: AndersKaseorg Thanks, fixed! It also seems a bit faster. @Simd , can you give an updated score?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg fixed, it should've been `N//2 + 1` instead of `(N+1)//2`

Comment: Your loop incorrectly counts the numbers whose generation *started* within 10 seconds, rather than the numbers whose generation *finished* within 10 seconds.

Comment: Swapping the `random() * N < …` rejection before the `sympy.isprime(p)` test seems to speed it up a bit.

Comment: It's much faster now!

Comment: @Simd I know, I made a rearrangement of the random test to partially do it before the power decomposition

Comment: I am looking forward to your speedups for the C++ code now!

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score = 14406

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

std::minstd_rand rng;
gmp_randstate_t gmp_rng;
double prob[1011];
const int maxV = 510510;
#define Vfactors {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17}
const int sqrtV = 715;
int sieve[maxV+1];
int primeps[maxV];
int primecnt = 0;
double logpq_sum[maxV];
int coprimes[92160];
std::uniform_int_distribution<> coprime_dist(0, 92159);
int coprimecnt = 0;
const double RAT = 510510. / 92160;
const double LOGV = 18.96157969569485;


void gen_factor(mpz_t N, int Nexp, double Nbase, mpz_t q, long int* qexp, double* qbase, mpz_t p, int* a, mpz_t Nq) {
    const double invN = 1 / Nbase;
    const double Nlog2 = Nexp + log2(Nbase);
    int I;
    for (I = 0; ; I++) {
        int i = I;
        double div = ldexp(invN*maxV, i-Nexp);
        if (div >= 1) break;
        prob[I] = (LOGV + i)*(1 + 1/(ldexp(maxV, i)-1)) + div*Nlog2;
    }
    int directI = I;
    const double finvN = ldexp(invN, -Nexp);
    prob[I++] = RAT * (logpq_sum[primecnt-1] + finvN * Nlog2 * (primecnt-1)); // small prime powers
    std::discrete_distribution<> distribution(std::begin(prob), std::begin(prob)+I);
    while (1) {
        int J = distribution(rng);
        if (J < directI) {
            const int i = J;
            mpz_urandomb(p, gmp_rng, i);
            mpz_setbit(p, i);
            mpz_mul_ui(p, p, maxV);
            mpz_add_ui(p, p, coprimes[coprime_dist(rng)]);
            if (mpz_cmp(p, N) > 0) continue;

            long pexp;
            double pbase = mpz_get_d_2exp(&pexp, p);

            double p_d = mpz_get_d(p);

            *a = 0;

            double logp = pexp + log2(pbase);
            double Nlogp = Nlog2 / logp;

            double choice_probability = (LOGV + i) / logp + Nlogp * finvN * (ldexp(maxV, i) - 1);

            #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << choice_probability << '\n';
            #endif

            double f = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(0, choice_probability)(rng);

            while (*a <= Nlogp && f >= 0) {
                ++*a;
                f -= (ldexp(maxV, i) - 1) * pow(p_d, -*a) + (ldexp(maxV, i) - 1)*finvN;
            }

            if (*a > Nlogp) continue;

            if (!mpz_probab_prime_p(p, 15)) continue;

            mpz_pow_ui(q, p, *a);
        } else { // small prime
            double f = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(0, logpq_sum[primecnt-1] + finvN * Nlog2 * (primecnt-1) )(rng);
            int l = 0;
            int r = primecnt-2;
            int ans = primecnt-1;
            while (l <= r) {
                int m = (l + r) / 2;
                double v = logpq_sum[m] + finvN * Nlog2 * m;
                if (v >= f) {
                    ans = m;
                    r = m-1;
                } else {
                    l = m+1;
                }
            }
            int pv = primeps[ans];
            mpz_set_ui(p, pv);
            
            double Nlogq = Nlog2 / log2(pv);

            f = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(0, 1 + Nlogq * (pv-1) * finvN )(rng);

            *a = 0;

            while (*a <= Nlogq && f >= 0) {
                ++*a;
                f -= (pv-1) * (pow(pv, -*a) + finvN);
            }

            if (*a > Nlogq) continue;

            mpz_ui_pow_ui(q, pv, *a);
        }

        *qbase = mpz_get_d_2exp(qexp, q);

        mpz_fdiv_q(Nq, N, q);
        int is_odd = mpz_odd_p(Nq);
        if (is_odd) mpz_add_ui(Nq, Nq, 1);
        double Nqd = mpz_get_d(Nq);
        if (!std::bernoulli_distribution(Nqd / (ldexp(Nbase / *qbase, Nexp - *qexp) + 1))(rng)) continue;
        if (is_odd) mpz_sub_ui(Nq, Nq, 1);
        return;
    }
}

void bach(mpz_t v, mpz_t target, std::vector<mpz_class>& factors) {
    if (mpz_cmp_ui(v, 1e7) < 0) {
        unsigned int vI = mpz_get_ui(v);
        int x = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(vI/2+1, vI)(rng);
        mpz_set_ui(target, x);
        factors.clear();
        for (int d = 2; d*d <= x; d++) {
            while (x % d == 0) {
                factors.emplace_back(d);
                x /= d;
            }
        }
        if (x != 1) {
            factors.emplace_back(x);
        }
        return;
    }
    mpz_t q, p, Nt;
    mpz_inits(q, p, Nt, 0);
    long int Nexp;
    double Nbase = mpz_get_d_2exp(&Nexp, v);
    while (1) {
        int a;
        long int qexp;
        double qbase;
        gen_factor(v, Nexp, Nbase, q, &qexp, &qbase, p, &a, Nt);
        bach(Nt, target, factors);
        long int targetexp;
        double targetbase = mpz_get_d_2exp(&targetexp, target);
        double logv = (log2(Nbase) + Nexp - 1)/(log2(qbase) + qexp + log2(targetbase) + targetexp);
        if (std::bernoulli_distribution(logv)(rng)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) factors.emplace_back(p);
            mpz_mul(target, target, q);
            mpz_clears(q, p, Nt, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void gen(int n, mpz_t target, std::vector<mpz_class>& factors) {
    mpz_t v;
    mpz_init2(v, n);
    mpz_setbit(v, n);
    mpz_sub_ui(v, v, 1);
    bach(v, target, factors);
}

int main() {

    rng.seed(time(0));
    gmp_randinit_lc_2exp_size(gmp_rng, 64);
    time_t end = time(0) + 10;
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = 1;
    for (int v : Vfactors) {
        for (int i = v; i <= maxV; i += v) sieve[i] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < maxV; i++) if (!sieve[i]) coprimes[coprimecnt++] = i;
    for (int v : Vfactors) sieve[v] = 0;
    double logpq_sum_v = 0;
    for (int v = 2; v <= maxV; v++) {
        if (!sieve[v]) {
            if (v <= sqrtV)
            for (int i = v*v; i <= maxV; i += v) sieve[i] = 1;
            logpq_sum[primecnt] = logpq_sum_v += log2(v) / (v-1);
            primeps[primecnt++] = v;
        }
    }
    int i;
    int tsz = 0;
    int primecnt = 0;
    for (i = 0; time(0) <= end; i++) {
        mpz_t target;
        mpz_init(target);
        std::vector<mpz_class> factors;
        gen(500, target, factors);
        tsz += factors.size();
        if (factors.size() == 1) primecnt++;
        #ifdef OUTPUT
        mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, target);
        printf(" = ");
        for (int j = 0; j < factors.size(); j++) {
            if (j) printf(" * ");
            std::cout << factors[j];
        }
        printf("\n");
        #endif
        mpz_clear(target);
    }
    std::cout << "generated " << i << " numbers\n";
    std::cout << "prime probability " << primecnt/double(i) << ", expected apprx. " << 0.0028879 /* (Li(2^500) - Li(2^499)) / 2^499 */ << '\n';
    std::cout << "average number of prime divisors " << tsz/double(i) << " expected apprx. " << log(500 * M_LN2) + 1.0345 /* B_2, see Wikipedia */ << '\n';
    
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVltb9s4Ev7uX8G2uKzkl9hy66SukwBb7GLhouseDu3eh65PkCXZYap3yaq3hf/65mb4YpES3St6RhJL5MxwZjjzcIbxs2y08/3Hx2c08aN9EJKbOvSrtLjrNSP@fZEmqTbilWVYVOpQ7GXqa@ElQRprPLFX3WsDZRVQTSxNy6oIPY1tF2eX962BwwGHesD/6lVME/h2cT1SJLtFD@bZW1l5VehWhL3jRJDuN1FIsiLdfHQmjrNe9PwUmAlNKhJ7hz/ILZk5E/hZ9J4F4ZYmIflj66E3SvJ1OiTPh2Q2JNdD4jjwC2/O9VERUeZFhTKundmixwZoWIcfUfIAF8OhrKBxmJVsUB3y4eGWTE5KRukuy91yH6uUfspoy4/zqXM1gUHmgH1Ct2kRu0DhBhQcSDf7iqbJzZ1kYMPWZEiAbza3NWGnhbkdYvl//fz@5IxLMiZswRbN23e/obXOy8v5lTO7nl/NZ1fzFy/B9l6vTmlAdmHicvdZcfYFdmI1ZH5ahYdsKKWsNl4ZDgknyIdgeLJDqj7JFTJ4U@myISfx5MAqt8nXHoGPpiJN6hWqCBawdRZdkhV4ego0qBQZoN@nFqO1OTEqvOSP4GViLZm3yIIsBwO5pqSjMCdo8SNWCGgN41EAC1ioUB93FAwY4ZJ2Q063xELaO1DYJhvIg0/NJAva5RoEWczvA0LtvuXAtzO2uGwh1h45tg3jIKrPjONCjidrAlpAhi8bXTV/bIXPGn2HRNWUKzIYoCoYJX1iNbEqI2rkrEEDLqovXAyEzbRtL8h4TMrYiyKeACRLP4dFydZgYQ0x6xdhFbZjWn21GOUm3NHEQsXsIWmPDJZC8c/3FMyznPamvQFDNJmAFa1deUNupNdU7sZ3cvPfLLRJjM09B8KNBTErkAg3qUtYhtWGVkhmmo33kbunOAs/uNMGGi8IGpoTVmgYgLatW6xoIbL7cYa8K5vckYmNllU02UPOaNQsPzOIB12IxFbMHHAEytuFgEfuFMPoImO5jDFk5HIDlcfq0PU9jlEmZow@mM2U/M2U/G1RrwQ5j8kx4zbL9e9T6ocuBpG3oRGt/tKST/DCMxfZP4V7Kx3JCNK5tcQzuoXzhfzy6@sPv2kTLHr9dF@RmxuTBjD605/JT7ppz8IkoFujEVvQWTskAFWiVkbhwdBdyhZ5oEkVOQTbcXMr7L64gEUAsibtzMDPYND3Fp3RLRndGr0EzgMUsCAcAHP6HqKYiazPPK3LPfY6MQ1a3nElzwYzkj3BuOOGuzxTWBo4M/ssG@NIP2Oy5SzZQNdGnSMJI0iCry2A@3@250cQltgtJJOAF/Fcag8XmESSfdqd95JSpXAWpsiIMDAKUyiwGgszKAK9C0yfaTcyhFvYedkUQCZL4y4zbiY7Pbem9fHDTTCw4gftj9tmqftp5EJnxgMTV@/8G6v6aulNqAZBsbXxRJB4Xrf28Ry05Tq0ARTW7Rz@3phzBLTlLK7qEUtPvg1GbDBidAcw8h8HDKmDxTCiPkEE08n@fjjIv5nXe6qmdt3O7Yahn5vPOl625qp7kGIL9ZibWyuQuuLTWuVYumkgD0F4Agxa5a0qhNPY6lHPpMGvY3eqzlWun6kdcU9EpVQk6T6KqBYBFnKPJfiychhe@6IGZ6XyCF6xKsQK1OYBofr1nOLlfnNOcSj29kUiq9WjaCI2nn8v2odaVvuVV4BRotbj7eoNq2AiaEvvIL54zyYDTClwcG0Q44TXNtR0Wgjuk5LukjBg@1EvFechT2u/Du0k6jZfVr0cTwfQKNbLNhIryS1NOSjTQv1LPwq9wlInsAFhJTwsP12QoB9gXh3gSW9GlNQ7kH8g@Zl8k0uFcRZ5UACAtz9Zgd1NwQMZQ5m8OANqR22/D@QJa2H05YxLHbTcMkeC9BhrD7FArRanMZrQqrTk@BCM5HOyi2SxyofUftNQofKmtP4fzYICTqclcq0YFsvkTbuJH6UVroeiARadLyh/wTHjQuQXPnpoj@IclgZooQwYGeMGhTiJSSs@c8YDJza5SBdUAD1rdoY3XTKeEhwPHHvMJ3I5kSs1ebM0zpzWaoHStzAJF5dA0wotmReUN@cUctuDL0wKY9hl5g7rlI3yOzfQsaw0xZwpepsIbhANYoEpm/wgnAkw1JNginGV2M2gaCfboxx@YbRuwJfFVm0KLVCZ341BN43LM3LYgcsyDAOrguLFmthCirx2Q23cyGdB5Zb0S2id2t6rF4IWOcEG6Ftgw4QYPEhEWcrvzSZ4xcAfHXx0lFsYhtHk1el6To0ILRpqFg23rGXGxwEM2UIqVaQeex1WhweS4MRY4sem4LU7LTaUxfxehH5TUy6gXjdlePvOz62bOUUIw/y6saZu3UA12tXrdorw4hhY2SWlfT596v73uqzBnXZzslbrdzBmcMsxoMay38IyTpcgy2Ddi3U3hU7lUnM3V5VfGmd1r1Mb@zg0yGAD@yD6xL5@1U5mmZD6eY1hbXVw0ZyyMoM0/Ldmk8m34BsNAUdJvGKZ00JHfQ4PdTigGqc1xOJ@4d2H9//88F4zI91XLmAqAi08AgZMDGgPIpNqaz0Flz01lR8P3JcPkB0tdclDtxBBzR/sRmhfE9q59RASPz6sTaWBlPJnogoRNyAdmNY37NjrLPYUNiYsvArKvqf4TtkgSfYxHEIlLLIw8Ij7SuVahvHKjRjzdLaozaiHBIAQIgSW8LKsOFxy6snlZDJ9@fJ6TsbQ0ryl1vQ/ECB4wcGeX8znNmuS8Yn0x/rNj66PV4MJu1BoTdKtuFGFjoOW@L8LtiDEV0szs2KQqRiqsE2/u29XU4bLl5PnL2ao6Gt3CudUGJJ/0080CwPqdXTrHR8f//a3kbcrH0cRYD//ezg8jt49/y8)

Can output around 15,000 numbers on my computer. Compile with `-lgmp -lgmpxx -O3`. Please make sure there aren't other programs active while running this, because I've noticed that on my computer it changed the number by almost 1,000, even with just Firefox.

### Explanation

This is an implemention of Bach's algorithm, although with a lot of optimizations.

The main function is `gen_factor`, which given \$n\$ returns \$q = p^\alpha\$ with probability \$\log(p) \#(\frac{n}{2q}, \frac nq] = \log(p) \lfloor\frac{\frac{N}{q} + 1}2\rfloor\$, where \$\#(a, b]\$ is the number of integers in that range.

We approximate that the floor isn't important, and then use rejection sampling to get back the appropriate distribution.

After multiplying by (the constant) \$\frac2N\$, we get \$\log(p)(\frac1q+\frac1N)\$. Now we group the terms by \$p\$, and for a given \$p\$ we have its probability being $$\log(p) \sum_{\alpha=1}^{\lfloor \log_p(N) \rfloor} (\frac1{p^\alpha}+\frac1N) = \log(p) (\frac1{p-1} - \frac1{p^{\lfloor \log_p(N) \rfloor}} + \frac{\lfloor \log_p(N) \rfloor}N) \leq \frac{\log(p)}{p-1} + \frac{\log(N)}{N}$$

We split the range to \$[2, 510510)\$, and \$[510510 \cdot2^i, 510510 \cdot2^{i+1})\$ for all \$i\$. For the first range, we precalculate stuff to get numbers with the correct probability. For each of the \$[510510 \cdot2^i, 510510 \cdot2^{i+1})\$ ranges we notice that the probability is decreasing, so we can just take the probability for \$p = 510510\cdot 2^i\$ and use rejection sampling. To lower the amount of numbers we have to generate, we require the numbers to be coprime to \$510510 = 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\$, so we need to multiply the probability by \$\frac{510510}{\varphi(510510)}\$ for the other segment.

Comment: @Simd Can you update how many numbers it generates on your computer?

Comment: Another large improvement!  I now get "unused variable ‘sz’ " in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: Updated.  This time bitcnt is unused and *a++ is computed but unused in the code.

Comment: @Simd oh, the order of operations there is wrong (so the distribution is slightly off), I'll fix that in a few hours. I should really compile it with `-Wall`

Comment: What further speedups do you think are possible?

Comment: @Simd now a significant part of the rejections are due to the primality tests failing, and I'm not sure what can be done about that. A slightly tighter envelope is possible, I might try that later.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you think the envelope can be tightened a little still?

Comment: @Simd I tried some stuff and it wasn't all that effective. Maybe you can get a few hundred more numbers, but not much more

Comment: Maybe you have reached the best that can be done!

Comment: What would I need to change if I wanted n to be much bigger? Say, 2000.   Currently it segfaults due to a memory writing error.

Comment: @Simd just the size of the array `prob` should be enough (to `2011`).

Comment: That works, thanks.

Comment: It's not important, but the code gives  a warning about the comparison of integer expressions of different signedness in:  `for (int j = 0; j < factors.size(); j++) {`

Answer (score 4):

## Rust + rand + bnum, score=4 on my PC

Basic implementation of Kalai's algorithm. Apparently it's not very good. The random rejection at the end rejects 99% of candidates so makes it take a lot longer.

```rs
use bnum::BUint;
use rand::{distributions::uniform::UniformSampler, Rng};

#[inline]
fn mod_exponentiate(mut base: BUint<16>, mut exponent: BUint<16>, modulus: BUint<16>) -> BUint<16> {
    if modulus == (1u64).into() {
        return 0u64.into();
    }

    let mut result: BUint<16> = (1u64).into();

    while !exponent.is_zero() {
        if exponent.digits()[0] & 1 == 1 {
            result = result * base % modulus
        }
        exponent >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus
    }

    return result;
}

#[inline]
fn miller_test(candidate: BUint<16>, mut d: BUint<16>, witness: BUint<16>) -> bool {
    let mut x = mod_exponentiate(witness, d, candidate);

    if x == (1usize).into() || x == candidate - BUint::<16>::from(1u64) {
        return true;
    }

    while d != candidate - BUint::<16>::from(1u64) {
        x = (x * x) % candidate;
        d <<= 1;

        if x == (1u64).into() {
            return false;
        }

        if x == candidate - BUint::<16>::from(1u64) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

#[inline]
fn prime_test(candidate: BUint<16>, iterations: usize, rng: &mut rand::rngs::ThreadRng) -> bool {
    if candidate == BUint::ONE {
        return false;
    }
    if candidate == BUint::TWO {
        return true;
    }
    if candidate == BUint::THREE {
        return true;
    }
    if candidate.digits()[0] & 1 == 0 {
        return false;
    }

    let mut d = candidate - BUint::<16>::from(1u64);
    if !d.is_zero() {
        d >>= d.trailing_zeros();
    }

    let distribution =
        bnum::random::UniformInt::<BUint<16>>::new(BUint::TWO, &(candidate - BUint::TWO));

    for _ in 0..iterations {
        let witness = distribution.sample(rng);
        if !miller_test(candidate, d, witness) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

#[inline]
fn kalai_algorithm(max: BUint<16>, rng: &mut rand::rngs::ThreadRng) -> (Vec<BUint<16>>, BUint<16>) {
    loop {
        let mut candidates: Vec<BUint<16>> = vec![];

        while candidates.last() != Some(&BUint::ONE) {
            candidates.push(rng.gen_range(BUint::ONE..*candidates.last().unwrap_or(&max)))
        }

        candidates.retain(|candidate| prime_test(*candidate, 8, rng));

        if let Some(possible_output) = candidates.iter().cloned().reduce(|a, b| (a * b).min(max)) {
            if possible_output < max && rng.gen_range(BUint::ONE..max) < possible_output {
                break (candidates, possible_output);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let start_time = std::time::Instant::now();
    let max = BUint::ONE << 500;

    let threads: Vec<_> = (0..8)
        .map(|thread_id| {
            std::thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
                loop {
                    let (factors, product) = kalai_algorithm(max, &mut rng);
                    if std::time::Instant::now() - std::time::Duration::from_secs(10) > start_time {
                        break;
                    }
                    println!("{thread_id}\t{product:?} {factors:?}")
                }
            })
        })
        .collect();

    threads.into_iter().for_each(|i| i.join().unwrap());
}
```

Run with:

```
opt-level=3
lto=true
panic="abort"
```

Comment: Hey, it scores 4 more than a Charcoal implementation...

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes, score 0 (usually)

```
≔Ｘ²ＮθＷ¹«≔⟦⊕‽⊖θ⟧υＷ⊖⌊υ⊞υ⊕‽⌊υ≔Φυ▷”8±cGＮºb6﹪←”κυ¿∧‹Πυθ‹‽θΠυ«⟦Ｉ⊞ＯυΠυ⟧Ｄ⎚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU85a8MwFJ7tXyEyPYFa0kKnTiFJIdDDdOgSMqi2Uovoio6EUPLbVT1jiKFa9I7vem3PfWu5ynkRgvwx0Niz8PDIyMa4FN@T/i4tpYwc6XN97qUSBB4o@a2rkbDdmNYLLUwUHXxy01kNK3EbHSmlO0ZSoVcjf7p@k0bqpCEVGGlS6CGh9z/JKQ6lRvcXqWIJWDjrE1df3MMsXLS73MvgvNRixsgB0w/2ck9gYTpE4/cqQoDG2y61sejiiYwMw9ET@9seH95dNV6aCNslDxEw8YcTnkc7pJjCd@hZrZJ2MFRLJUo@LK/1Neen@TzfndQf) Link is to verbose version of code with extra check because the version of Charcoal on TIO returns `None` for the product of an empty list and I can't use the version of Charcoal on ATO for multiple reasons. Note that you need to interrupt (`^C` if running locally or TIO's button) the code manually after ten seconds otherwise it will never print anything. Explanation: Uses Kalai's inefficient algorithm.

```
≔Ｘ²Ｎθ
```

Get `2ⁿ`.

```
Ｗ¹«
```

Repeat forever.

```
≔⟦⊕‽⊖θ⟧υ
```

Start with a random integer between `0` and `2ⁿ` exclusive.

```
Ｗ⊖⌊υ
```

Until a `1` is generated...

```
⊞υ⊕‽⌊υ
```

... push a random integer between `1` and the previous integer to the list.

```
≔Φυ▷”8±cGＮºb6﹪←”κυ
```

Filter out all non-primes from the list.

```
¿∧‹Πυθ‹‽θΠυ«
```

If the product is less than `2ⁿ` and passes a random chance, then...

```
⟦Ｉ⊞ＯυΠυ⟧Ｄ⎚
```

... output the primes and their product.

83 bytes for a version that times itself:

```
≔Ｘ²Ｎθ≔▷clock⟦⟧ηＷ‹⁻▷clock⟦⟧ηχ«≔⟦⊕‽⊖θ⟧υＷ⊖⌊υ⊞υ⊕‽⌊υ≔Φυ▷”8±cGＮºb6﹪←”κυ¿∧‹Πυθ‹‽θΠυ⟦Ｉ⊞ＯυΠυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBJa8MwEIXPya8QOY1ALW6hp55CFwh0MT30YnxQZbUW0eJoSQilv10dGdMYSk5iZj6992ZEz71wXOe8DkF9WajdQXq4ZmRjhxRfkvnAklJGdvR2OTEPe67fuYeV0E5sV4w0LQI9AodeaUngSYYAz8qmcJZl5KqilHwvF5Nos7HCSyNtlB28cds5A/fy1NpRSltGErosJpv5GN2USQYSYqROoYdUdvgnOeeK1OT@qHTERfHPX@BwNMPxUoXBKyMx@LZcYbRXnwTWtit0ecZta@@6JCLqllMxMjYnz1Kf5nRM6JWN0NzxEKGkfR2k59GNCeZoi34/Od9UVb7Y618) Link is to verbose version of code with extra check because the version of Charcoal on TIO returns `None` for the product of an empty list and I can't use the version of Charcoal on ATO because it doesn't have access to `sympy.isprime`. Note that the timing is approximate and might generate an extra result which actually finished outside the desired time.

64 bytes for a version that finds one factorisation and exits:

```
⊞υＸ²Ｎ≔⊖⌈υθＷ∨›Πυθ›‽θΠυ«≔⟦⊕‽θ⟧υＷ⊖⌊υ⊞υ⊕‽⌊υ≔Φυ▷”8±cGＮºb6﹪←”κυ»Ｉ⊞ＯυΠυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NSwMxEIbP3V8ReppAWorgqSfRKj1oFw9exEPcHbqh@dhOktYi/vaYyK61YG4ZnneeeZtOUuOkTqmOvoMoWO2OSHAl2Nr2MTxF856/nPNldeO92lq4w4bQoA3YwqP8UCYaiJwLts/MsVMaGWwIHghlyNGaXBubkJFCCDbOn6VtnYEyOiP5sc9qMphe1/as@uX5m2AxqyaD6@IeZcd7OBsb/bPlL1dWDcJ7pctpObM6SP0iCab@ZPrTXPmelMGpYLvStOi/qpqUDXArfYCi2vRIMrif@EWjZUrXi0WaHfQ3) Link is to verbose version of code. Still usually crashes out because it can't calculate the product of an empty list, and even when it does find a result, it usually takes more than 10 seconds, but just in case, here's a bash script that restarts the program on error and times out after 10 seconds:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyQzNzW/tERBt1jBIzRAwdBAIQksXp6RmZOqYMWVkq@gn19Qop@ckViUnJ@YA2co6CYrqD/qmne@9f2eHYc2vd@z7lHnlEdd0x71dJxvPbfj/Z7tjzpWPGrYdW4BiAtkPGrYe24HiHdoNUjl/GWPuqaCxR7NXw4yZDtYc9f5VrChEEkIv3PKuWVAatr2Rw1zLQ5tTHYHWnZoV5LZ@52rHrVNAAqe2wU0dff7PSuBWt/vWQ@0EGiNuoJupoKpgYGCkZ1@SmqZfl5pTo6CmppCanJGPowGei8vFQA)

Answer (score -3):

### Jelly (12 bytes) Score: 0

Edit: old code was wrong

> 2*³XȮÆ!Ṅ
>  ç1¿

New code:
2*³XȮÆEṄ
>! ç1¿

```
2*³..... 2^input
...X.... Pick a random number in [0, 2^input)
....Ȯ... Print the random number
.....ÆE. Factorize it
.......Ṅ Print the factors and go to line
ç1¿..... Loop the function above forever
```

Old code:

> Jelly beginner, the code can likely be shortened. It generated 141'808 random numbers between [0, 2^500) in 10 seconds on my MacBook Pro M2, the generated filesize is 68Mb.
>  Try the code here: https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//MirCs1jIrsOGIeG5hArDpzHCv////zUwMA

New code has a score of 0.

Testing code:

```
> ./jelly fu prime.jelly 500 > primelist.txt & pid=$!; sleep 10; kill $pid
> wc -l primelist.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You can't factorize a 500 bit number quickly.

Comment: According to the Jelly codepage, `Æ` starts a two byte arithmetic monad, so you're actually doing `Æ!` which converts the number to factorial base.